# For loops and computing moving averages

Tags: java, matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to rewrite my MATLAB code in Java and I'm having a strange problem. It only repeats the first value but it does loop for the correct size of the ArrayList.

MATLAB Code

```
function m = ema(x,N)
    L = length(x);
    m = zeros(L,1);
    w = 2/(N+1);
    m(1) = x(1);
    for i=2:L
        m(i) = w*(x(i)-m(i-1)) + m(i-1);
    end
end
```

Java Code

```
public static ArrayList<Double> getEma(ArrayList<Double> x, int frame) {
    ArrayList<Double> m = new ArrayList<>();
    double w = (2 / (frame + 1));

    m.add(x.get(0));

    for (int i=1; i < x.size(); i++) {
        double value = (w * (x.get(i) - m.get(i-1))) + m.get(i-1);
        m.add(value);
    }

    return m;
}
```

JUnit Test Results

```
Expected :[23.11, 23.32, 23.78, 24.06, 24.29, 24.19, 23.82, 23.53, 23.63, 23.62, 23.41, 23.23, 23.51, 23.79, 24.13, 24.69, 25.05, 25.37, 25.53, 25.56, 25.84, 25.73, 25.88, 25.45, 25.01, 24.8, 24.44, 24.18, 24.58, 25.37]
Actual   :[23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11, 23.11]
```

Comment: may be your w is zero. so (w * (x.get(i) - m.get(i-1))) is always zero..

Comment: what is teh value of frame?

Comment: @hermit you're correct(ish). The test frame values were 5 and 8 but they were ints. I thought that wouldn't be a problem but I just outputted that line and I got a `w=0` so I switched a frame to a `double` and it solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SARose - You can also change the numbers to `2.0` and `1.0` so that the calculation gets automatically type cast to `double`.  This avoids having to cast `frame`, and also maintains the original method declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the input from `int frame` to `double frame` or cast the `frame` to a `double` or turn `2` -> `2.0` and `1` -> `1.0` to automatically convert to a double without casting when computing w.

```
public static ArrayList<Double> getEma(ArrayList<Double> x, int frame) {
    ArrayList<Double> m = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double w = (2 / ((double) frame + 1));

    m.add(x.get(0));

    for (int i=1; i < x.size(); i++) {
        double value = (w * (x.get(i) - m.get(i-1))) + m.get(i-1);
        m.add(value);
    }

    return m;
}
```